# What causes adiabatic expansion?

Tags: thermodynamics, adiabatic

What creates the force in the adiabatic system to expand the piston in the Carnot engine to move up without any changes in the thermodynamical factors? Can you please tell me what causes it?

Comment: Isn't everything in thermodynamics caused by pressure gradients [mildly facetious]?

Comment: What do you consider "thermodynamical factors"?  I've never heard that term, and it seems vague.

Comment: If you're actually looking for an example of what could cause adiabatic expansion in a piston-- combustion of fuel.

Answer (score 1):

Gases expand when the force which they exert on the moveable piston due to their pressure is greater than the external force exerted on the piston. This is the same for adiabatic or isothermal or any other kind of expansion. Similar applies for contraction.

In such an expansion there **are** changes in thermodynamic variables. There can be changes in volume, pressure, temperature, internal energy, number of moles, etc. During an adiabatic process there is no transfer of heat into or out of the gas, but there can be work done by or on the gas which can change the temperature and internal energy of the gas.

Comment: By Newton’s 3rd law, the pressure that the gas exerts on the walls of the container must be equal to the pressure the walls of the container exert on the gas.

Answer (score 0):

When the gas is expanding, the pressure of the gas within the container is not uniform spatially.  It is lowest at the piston face, and higher on average within the cylinder.  So there is a pressure driving force (i.e., pressure gradient) for the gas to experience an expansional deformation.